# Bivariate cointegration in a multiple regression error correction model

Tags: time-series, cointegration, ecm

I am new to cointegration and ECM.

I have two I(1) variables that I have estimated and their linear combination is I(0) as per the Engle-Granger test.

Is it then possible to use this error-correcting term in an OLS regression with additional exogenous variables? (i.e., z in the below example)

Example:
$$
y_{t} =  \alpha +   \gamma x_{t} +  u_{t} 
$$

After, the above is estimated it is added as the error correction in the below ECM:

$$
\Delta y_{t} = c + \beta_{1}\Delta x_{t-1} + \beta_{2}\Delta y_{t-1} + \beta_{3}\Delta z_{t-1} + \delta( {y}_{t-1} -  \widehat{a} -  \widehat{\gamma}x_{t-1})
$$

Comment: Why is $y$ without an index but $x$ and $u$ indexed by $i$ rather than $t$? Is $\Delta y$ missing an index $_t$? Why is there a hat over $y_{t-1}$?

Comment: Sorry, corrected, still getting the hand of notation in LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should be possible as long as $\Delta z_{t-1}$ is I(0). Then both the left hand side and the right hand side are I(0) and thus you have a balanced regression.